# Update 1000+ Records using JDBC -

Tags: java, performance, spring-jdbc

> Hi, I'm trying to update **1000+ records** using ***Java Database
> Connection (JDBC)*** but my solution doesn't work:

```
Connection c = null;
Statement statement = null;
String color = "init";
try{
String builder= "SELECT COLOR,SHAPE FROM TBL_SHAPES"; // this line of code will fetch 1000+ records of data from the database.
c = getConnection();
statement = c.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(builder.toString());
if(rs.getFetchSize() > 0) {
while(rs.next()) {
    color = rs.getString("COLOR");
        if(!color.equalsIgnoreCase("init")) {//this code will check if the color is not "init" 
           switch(color) {
              case "green":
               rs.updateString("SHAPE", "TRIANGLE");
                  break;
                case "orange":
                   rs.updateString("SHAPE", "CIRCLE");
                  break;
                  case "yellow":
                    rs.updateString("SHAPE", "SQUARE");
                   break;
         }
       }
       rs.updateRow();
     }
    }}
```

> Is there any efficient way to update 1000+ records? Thank you in
> advance!

Comment: why you are not using update query?

Comment: I tried Update query also but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you share the query u used?

Comment: UPDATE TBL_SHAPES SET SHAPE = ? WHERE COLOR = ?

Comment: first I fetched the 1000+ records using select statement, I put it in a List then update it in a separate function using for each loop.

Comment: The update query is correct , it should work, you need to use statement.executeUpdate

Comment: yes, I used executeUpdate before, it works in 100 records but when the records are 1000+ records it will have an issue, deadlock victim. so I used addBatch and executeBatch but it doesn't work also.

Comment: Which database server your using?, In case you have large number of records, add index to the table.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: updating 1000 rows many not be a problem for SQL server, it can handle much higher, In case you have large number of rows , add an index to table, for color column

Comment: I will update the records using index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use update query to update the table

```
Connection c = null;
  PreparedStatement statement = null;
  String color = "init";
  try{
     String builder= "UPDATE TBL_SHAPES SET SHAPE = ? WHERE COLOR = ? ";  
     c = getConnection();
     statement = c.prepareStatement(builder);
     statement.setString(1, "TRIANGLE");
     statement.setString(2, "green");
     statement.addBatch();
     statement.setString(1, "CIRCLE");
     statement.setString(2, "orange");
     statement.addBatch();
     statement.setString(1, "SQUARE");
     statement.setString(2, "yello");
     statement.addBatch();
     int[] result = statement.executeBatch();

  }catch(Exception e){
    
  }
```

You can use a code like this to fix it. Hope this is your requirement

Comment: I used this code before, but it gets an error, **deadlock issue**, I put a counter variable so that if that counter variable reached 100 records the executeBatch() function will execute the remaining records will execute outside the loop..

Comment: DId u try in transaction mode, connection.setAutoCommit(false);

Comment: Can you share table structure?.  Issue will be mostly related to that

Comment: I tried also this: connection.setAutoCommit(false) but it gets an error: Cannot call Connection.commit in distributed transaction.  Transaction Manager will commit the resource manager when the distributed transaction is committed.

Comment: I think there's no problem with getConnection()